# How to extend a full tree-like class hierarchy

Tags: c#, design-patterns, serialization

I have a class hierarchy which consists only of data. For example:

```
class A 
{
    List<B> b { get; set; }
    C c { get; set; }
}

class B 
{ 
    int d { get; set; }
}

class C 
{
    List<int> e { get; set; }
}
```

The class hierarchy is prepared for serialization using both XML and protobuf-net. It also lives in a separate library since it needs to be used by two different applications.

Now I need to create an *extended* version of this class hierarchy, where the number of nodes and their relations are the same, but there can be extra data, methods or properties in each of them. For example:

```
class AA : A
{
    int extra { get; set; }
}

class BB : B
{
    float extra { get; set; }
    void something();
}

class CC : C
{
    float extra { get; set; }
}
```

One problem I see with the above is that all the (inherited) references between classes are still using types from the original hierarchy, i.e. `List<B>` instead of `List<BB>`, so I would have to cast to the new types all the time. A bigger problem is that I also need to be able to serialize the *original* hierarchy from the extended one, which I have not been able to do when every instance is of the derived type.

**Question:** Is there a way to extend a full class hierarchy, so that I can have a shared pure data object model somewhere, and still be able to add more information and behaviors externally without losing the original structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a simplified version of the **[Extension Object](http://www.mif.vu.lt/~plukas/resources/Extension%20Objects/ExtensionObjectsPattern%20Gamma96.pdf)** design pattern.

**Step 1)**

First I created the following interface and abstract base class to be used by extensions and extensible objects respectively:

```
public interface IExtension 
{
    bool IsSerializable { get; }
}

public abstract class Extensible
{
    public static bool ShouldSerializeExtensions = true;

    public IExtension Extension { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeExtension()
    {
        return ShouldSerializeExtensions &&
               Extension != null &&
               Extension.IsSerializable;
    }
}
```

The static `ShoulSerializeExtensions` flag allows me to temporarily enable or disable serialization of extensions as a whole, while the `IsSerializable` property allows me to create extensions that are not supposed to be serialized at all.

*Note: Before serializing I also need to provide a list of all the concrete extension types that I create.*

**Step 2)**

I made every node in the hierarchy inherit from `Extensible` and created extension classes for each of them:

```
public class A : Extensible
{
    List<B> b { get; set; }
    C c { get; set; }
}

public class B  : Extensible
{ 
    int d { get; set; }
}

public class C  : Extensible
{
    List<int> e { get; set; }
}

public class ExtensionA : IExtension
{
    bool IsSerializable { get { return true; } }
    int extra { get; set; }
}

public class ExtensionB : IExtension
{
    bool IsSerializable { get { return true; } }
    float extra { get; set; }
    void something();
}

public class ExtensionC : IExtension
{
    bool IsSerializable { get { return true; } }
    float extra { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 3)**

I created a **[Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)** to ensure that every node gets created with the correct extension object attached.

```
public static class Factory
{
    public static A CreateA()
    {
        var a = new A();
        a.Extension = new ExtensionA();
        return a;
    }

    ...
}
```

And I also created extension methods to make manipulating the extensions easier without having to cast to the correct type every time.

```
public static class ExtensionUtils
{
    public static ExtensionA GetExtension(this A a)
    {
       return a.Extension as ExtensionA;
    }

    ...
}
```

**Example)**

With everything in place, I can create an extended object and change its values like this:

```
var a = Factory.CreateA();
a.GetExtension().extra = 20;
```

And I can serialize the hierarchy with or without extensions by setting the global `Extensible.ShouldSerializeExtensions` flag before serializing.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do what you want using generics. At least for the solution to prevent the casting.
I'm still thinking about how to serialize the original hierachy from the extended one.

Your B, BB, C and CC classes from your question are still the same.

First a generic A class:

```
class A<BType, CType> where BType: B where CType: C {
    List<BType> b { get; set;}
    CType c { get; set;}
}
```

Then the non-generic A class which uses the generic A class:

```
class A: A<B, C> {
}
```

And the (non-generic) AA class which also uses the generic A class:

```
class AA: A<BB, CC> {
    int extra { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 Very interesting use of generics! I have implemented it and it does solve part of the equation, although it can get crazy on an actual implementation, where there can be a large number of children types. It works well for adding the new data, although the original model needs to be built with extensibility already in mind. The XmlSerializer worked well when serializing AA, but protobuf-net broke. I have tried adding subtype information at runtime to the serializer, and it serialized, but the data came back empty. As for how to serialize the original hierarchy, I'm still clueless :)